# inner html radio button array value getting over written in for loop

Tags: javascript, html

I have written this code which should simply display the user's selection based on radio button clicked, There are multiple groups of radio buttons in the one form

```
<form name="makePicks">
    <label class="green">
        <input type="radio" id="x" onclick="handleClick()" name="picks1" value="Chiefs"><span>Chiefs</span>

        </label>
        <label class="yellow">
            <input type="radio" onclick="handleClick()" name="picks1" value="Hurricanes"><span>'Hurricanes'</span>

        </label>
        <label class="pink">
            <input type="radio" name="picks1" value="draw" onclick="handleClick()"><span>Draw</span>

        </label>
        <br />
        <label class="green">
            <input type="radio" id="x" onclick="handleClick()" name="picks2" value="Lions"><span>Lions</span>

        </label>
        <label class="yellow">
            <input type="radio" onclick="handleClick()" name="picks2" value="Stormers"><span>'Stormers'</span>

        </label>
        <label class="pink">
            <input type="radio" name="picks2" value="draw" onclick="handleClick()"><span>Draw</span>

        </label>
        <br />
    </form>
    <div id="dispPicks">
            </div>

function handleClick() {
    // Get all the inputs.
    var inputs = makePicks.elements;
    var radios = [];

    //Loop and find only the Radios
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
        if (inputs[i].type == 'radio') {
            radios.push(inputs[i]);
        }
    }

    //var found = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
             document.getElementById("dispPicks").innerHTML="YOU HAVE SELECTED "+radios[i].value
            //found = 0;
            //break;
        }
    }
    //if (found == 1) {
        //alert("Please Select Radio");
        //}
        //event.preventDefault(); // disable normal form submit behavior
        return false; 
    }
```

**My problem is**

The value of the array `radios[i].value` gets over written as you can see in the image below

[image]

In this example cheifs and Stormers both needs to be displayed, since it was selected

If anyone can help me with correct implementation it would be very much appreciated

I created a fiddle at this link https://jsfiddle.net/taditdash/w8hpQ/

Answer (score 4):

You can modify your JavaScript code like this:

```
function handleClick() {
    // Get all the inputs.
    var inputs = makePicks.elements;
    var radios = [];

    //Loop and find only the Radios
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
        if (inputs[i].type == 'radio') {
            radios.push(inputs[i]);
        }
    }

    myradiovalue = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            if (myradiovalue=="")
                myradiovalue=radios[i].value
            else
                myradiovalue=myradiovalue+ ", " +radios[i].value    
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("dispPicks").innerHTML = "YOU HAVE SELECTED " + myradiovalue;
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: lets say I want to add a select box to each group of radio buttons any idea how I will modify above code so that team1Name+score1, team2Name+score2 will be displayed?

Comment: Yes, I can help you in this, it will be great if you can come up in private chat window and give me more details or page access..

Comment: Or if you can prefer Skype?

Comment: @PratapPatil please send me your skype name

Comment: Skype ID; pratapvashi